# Combinatoria de letras en R

Tags: r

Tengo letras, por ejemplo: `(abc)`

Quiero sus combinaciones.
Necesito un vector con salida `("a-b" "a-c" "b-c")`.

Uso la función:

```
CL<-combn(letters[1:3], 2,simplify = T)
CL.1 <-c(as.vector(CL))
CL.1
```

Pero no puedo darle esa salida.

¿Pueden ayudarme con esta salida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@toto28,

Una manera de realizar lo que deseas es:

Primero, usar la funcion para obtener las combincaiones. Es importante no simplificar para que cada combinación aparezca como elemento de una lista

```
 CL <- combn(letters[1:3], 2, simplify = FALSE)
```

Luego usas la función `lapply` en conjunto con la función `paste` (y su argumento `collapse = "-"`. Esto aplicará la función `paste` para cada elemento de la lista, ie, para cada combinación.

```
CL.1 <- lapply(CL, paste, collapse = "-")
```

Finalmente, dado que lapply retorna también una lista, esta la puede convertir en un vector con la función `unlist`

```
unlist(CL.1)
```

Comment: Muy buena solución, funciona correcto!! Muchas Gracias